# Length of the Hypotenuse of a Triangle formed by Radius/Radian Lengths in a Circle

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find the length of the hypotenuse of a triangle formed when you take a circle with a radius of 1, travel 1 rad around the perimeter, and then draw a perpendicular line of 1 unit (radius length) from that position, intersecting the original radius (see image).

In the below image it's the green x I'm trying to find.

Thank you in advance.

[Position of End Radius after Traveling 1 Rad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk31V.png)

(This question has been answered. Thank you.)

Comment: $\sqrt {(1-\cos 1)^2+(1-\sin 1)^2   }$

Comment: A sketch: the bigger triangle has leg lengths $\sin 1$ and $\cos 1$ (why?);  make the appropriate subtractions to get the legs of the smaller triangle, and use Pythagoras from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the principles of the unit circle to deduce the coordinates of the intersection between the red and green line.

First, we attempt to find the coordinates of intersection between the blue line and the circle.

Since the coordinates of any angle $\theta$ going counterclockwise on a unit circle is $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$, they are:
$(\cos(1),\sin(1))$. Now, since the red line is going down by $1$ unit, the coordinates of the intersection between the red and green line is $(\cos(1),\sin(1)-1)$

Now, we may use Pythagoras's theorem to deduce the distance between $(1,0)$ and $(\cos(1),\sin(1)-1)$. Therefore, the answer will be:

$$x=\sqrt{(\cos(1)-1)^2+(\sin(1)-1)^2}$$

Comment: Are you sure that's supposed to be a subtraction in the last result?

Comment: My apologies, I am editing my answer right now.

Comment: Thank you. What if the angle was going clockwise instead? Would I just invert the cos and sin to be $(sin(θ),cos(θ))$?

Comment: Actually, you would substitute $\theta$ for $-\theta$ instead. Therefore, $(\cos(-\theta),\sin(-\theta))$ would be your coordinates. However, note that $\sin(-\theta) \equiv -\sin(\theta)$and $\cos(-\theta) \equiv \cos(\theta)$. Therefore, this simplifies to $(\cos(\theta), -\sin(\theta))$

Comment: Out of curiosity, in the equation above the intersection of the radius and the perpendicular line is just past half the radius, Is there a simple way of calculating where a perpendicular line from half a radius going to the circumference (either clockwise or counterclockwise) would land in rads?

Comment: You are asking whether you can find the coordinates of the intersection of the red line and the green line given any value of $\theta$? In that case, the coordinates are $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)-1)$. Please correct me if this did not answer your question.

Comment: Otherwise, if you mean finding the angle $\phi$ between the origin and the intersection between the red and the green line, use the fact that "Tangent is opposite over adjacent". Hence, your expression for any angle $\phi \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ (1st and 4th quadrant) is $\phi=\arctan(\frac{\sin(\theta)-1}{\cos(\theta)})$. For $1$ rad, substitute $\theta=1$.

Comment: I'm no math expert, so forgive me if your above response was the answer. Since my previous question intersects the radius at approximately 0.54 units (using 1 rad for the segment along the circumference), if that perpendicular line were moved over to exactly 0.5 units on the radius how long would the segment along circumference become? Or rather, what's the formula you would use? It seems like you answered above, but when I plug in .5 into θ I get -0.5354, which makes no sense since the length should be greater than 1.

Comment: $\phi$ is the angle in radians from the origin to the intersection between the red and green line, not the arclength. The arclength $s$, which you called "The segment along circumference" can be determined by using $s=r \theta$. For your initial question where $\theta=1 rad$, the arclength $s$ will be $s=1 \cdot1=1$. Does this answer your question? If you have doubts whether it does, here is an image showing what I think you mean by the length of the line segment along the circumference: http://www.1728.org/radians2.png

Comment: Hence, for the question about the $x$-coordinate being on exactly $0.5$ units on the radius, you would let $0.5=\cos(\theta)$ to find the angle $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Hence, since $r=1$, the arclength $s=1 \cdot \frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\pi}{3}$ units. This is approximately $1.047$, which is greater than $1$.

Comment: Thank you! That clears it up immensely! It's been forever since I've taken calc and I seem to have forgotten most of it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the horizontal line. From the origin until the intersection with the red line, there's a distance of $\cos(1)$, so the base of the triangle whose hypotenuse you're trying to find is

$$1-\cos(1).$$

Similarly, the height is

$$1-\sin(1).$$

So the hypotenuse is...?